# Match two different rules (javascript regexp)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write regexp that could find a string that validates as a function argument and asterisk. I write that 

`'some*'.match(/^[a-z0-9]+|(\*$)/i)`

But it not found asterisk. second result item is just undefined..

I plan to get string "some" and "*", also if you search in some word without asterisk at the end it must to find only that word.

Comment: The pipe symbol (`|`) means the regex stops evaluating your string after finding the first match

Comment: `'some*'.match(/^[a-z0-9]+|\*$/gi)` - you only searched for the first match, `g` will enable multiple searches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional capturing group around the first `[a-z0-9]` part and the second one should be made optional with `?`.

Also, the `|` should not be there, as that's specifying two different alternatives, so your `RegExp` is actually trying to match `/^[a-z0-9]+/i` and, if it doesn't, then it tries `/(\*$)/i`, which is not what you want. That's why you get `undefined` even if the asterisk is there and also why anything that ends with an asterisk and doesn't start with `a-z0-9`, like `_*`, will also match.

Here's an example with all these changes:

```js
const match1 = 'some'.match(/^([a-z0-9]+)(\*)?$/i);
const match2 = 'some*'.match(/^([a-z0-9]+)(\*)?$/i);

console.log(match1);
console.log(match2);
```

If you want to get rid of the first match and only get the asterisk one if it is there, you can use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
 and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
:

```js
const match1 = ('some'.match(/^([a-z0-9]+)(\*)?$/i) || []).slice(1).filter(Boolean);
const match2 = ('some*'.match(/^([a-z0-9]+)(\*)?$/i) || []).slice(1).filter(Boolean);

console.log(match1);
console.log(match2);
```